# Is it possible to use firebase and express together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to express and i wanted to build a rest api  from express.js that uses firebase as database. is it possible for them to work together? i tried doing this...

```js
const firebase = require("firebase")
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require( 'cors');

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
app.use(cors())
let data;
firebase.database().ref("public").on("value", snapshot =>{
  data = snapshot.val();
})
app.get("/api", (req, res)=>{
  res.send(data)
})

app.listen(3500, ()=>console.log("listening at port 3500..."))
```

But it didnt work, the server keeps on disconnecting, the server does not respond  and i have to start it again. And when i go to "port: 3500" the server stops responding  I heard about cloud function but we need pay for it. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail? Which server, the firebase server or your own server? What is the expected output and what actually happens?

Comment: I assume that you filled in "xxxxxxx" on the server end

Comment: You will need to provide more debugging details.  "The server keeps disconnecting" isn't enough information to understand what you're doing wrong.  Firebase and express are common to use together - it's up to use to use them correctly.

Comment: @ARIFISHER this will be my rest api, it will be on my own server. I had made my app from react, and when a user goes to my react app it should request this api to show all the data from firebase,

Comment: Getting better, but you should say which server.

Comment: @DougStevenson the server does not respond and i have to start it again. And again when i go to "port: 3500" the server stops responding.

Comment: @ARIFISHER my own server

Comment: @DougStevenson i couldnt find any video or tutorial on how to use them together. Can you  tell me how to do it?

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: @arifisher the console out put is "listening at port 3500...," and there are no error output, the server just ends by itelf, and when i log the `data` theres no output

Comment: App.get only works with GET stuff. Are you making a REST request to /api? You can use app.rest("/api", etc) if that's the case.

Comment: okay i don't know about rest please ignore that last comment

Comment: @ArFISHER hmm so i actually have a app, and when i  click a button on the app it should do this fetch the response from `http://localhost:3500/api` and the response should be the data from firebase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226104/discussion-between-ari-fisher-and-djbillje-official).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're only reading the data when the api is requested, and you aren't sending a response. Here's how I fixed it:

```
firebase.database().ref("public").on("value", snapshot =>{
data = snapshot.val();
})

app.get("/api", (req, res)=>{
    res.send(data)

})
```

Replace your app.get with this code, and it should work.

Comment: So your question actually fixed it, so that should work.